# Angular 2 Can't bind to 'dragula' since it isn't a known property of 'div'

Tags: angular

Please see the following screen capture for more info.

I am using dragula module and after npm install got the following error.

[image: Dragula_Error_ScrrenShot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import Dragula Module in `app.module.ts`

```
import {DragulaModule , DragulaService} from "ng2-dragula/ng2-dragula"

@NgModule({
  imports: [
     DragulaModule
  ],
declarations: []
})
```

Comment: I would like to add that if you have organised your app into modules then not only do you need to add the Dragula module into the app.module.ts you also have to add it into the module that the component you want to use it in is part of.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the module to `imports` of the module where you are using dragula

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, /* or CommonModule */ 
    DragulaModule, 
    /* OtherModule */
  ],
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

adding this line in to pollyfills.ts fixed my problem

(window as any).global = window;